# Generalization of SVD algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, fields, singular-values

Let $K$ be a field, $A\in K^{n\times m}$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ the Euclidean norm. Consider the problem: Find a $v\in K^m$ such that
\begin{align}
\lVert Av\rVert=\min_{\lVert x\rVert=1}\lVert Ax\rVert
\end{align}
This minimization problem can be solved for $K=\mathbb{R},K=\mathbb{C}$ with the SVD-algorithm. The corrosponding right-singular vector of the smallest singular value is a solution (If $A=U\Sigma V^*$ is the SVD and the singular values on the diagonal of $\Sigma$ are sorted by their absolute value then the rightmost column of $V$ solves the problem).

However, I am now looking for a more general method of solving this problem for any field $K$. Is there a generalization of the SVD-algorithm that maybe preserves this property?

Edit: The same method works for algebraic numbers (The singular value problem can be reduced to the eigenvalue problem which is closed under the algebraic numbers). The comments pointed quaternionics as well.

Comment: The SVD works well with quaternionic matrices.

Comment: It won't work for "any" field $K$ - you at least need that the minimum value and a minimiser to be expressible in this field.

Comment: And what is a norm on a vector space over $K$?

Comment: Also, even over $K = \mathbb{R}$ or $K = \mathbb{C}$, the minimum in question can only be computed via the SVD if the norm being used on $K^m$ is the Euclidean norm (i.e., $2$-norm). For many other norms (e.g., the $p$-norms when $p \in (1,2) \cup (2,\infty)$), this problem is NP-hard.

Comment: The norm does not matter, but I'll write Euclidean norm in the question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik what do you mean by "expressible"? $\mathbb{R}$ is not computable, meaning an implementation requires approximation but the algorithm still is correct.

Comment: you end up working in a computable fragment of $\mathbb{R}$, one way or another - you need to specify the input after all. As long as you are happy working with algebraic numbers and vectors of algebraic numbers, it all can be done algorithmically. (Although rather inefficiently in practice). 

Anyway, the problem is about finding the minimal eigenvalue of $AA^*$, after that $v$ may be found by solving a linear system.